# Why Can't I override draw method from cocos2d::sprite?

Tags: cocos2d-x

I need to override draw method from sprite to apply some custom stuff, but it doesnt hit my draw override at all. I'm pretty sure I am doing it correctly:

.h file:

```
virtual void draw(cocos2d::Renderer* renderer, const cocos2d::Mat4& transform, bool transformUpdated);
```

.cpp file:

```
void CustomSprite::draw(cocos2d::Renderer* renderer, const cocos2d::Mat4& transform, bool transformUpdated)
{
    int x = 0;   //breakpoint here
}
```

my class is

```
#include "cocos2d.h"

class CustomSprite : public cocos2d::Sprite
{
```

Comment: Are you sure the instance on which `draw` is called is actually of type `EnergyManager`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was:

```
in .h:
virtual void draw(cocos2d::Renderer *renderer, const cocos2d::Mat4 &transform, uint32_t flags) override;

in .cpp:
void EnergyManager::draw(cocos2d::Renderer* renderer, const cocos2d::Mat4& transform, uint32_t flags)
```

thanks to Kobyle